# Using managed code with Mono embedding

Tags: c#, c++, .net, mono, jit

I am trying to embed managed c# code to c++ (with the help of tutorial in http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono and examples included in samples).

However I cannot get it to work. I think it is very possible that the problem is with a `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient` object (for instance I can access values and methods of some other classes but if I add a `TcpClient` object to a class I encounter problems.

Here is some simple C# code I wrote to test just adding a TCPClient object

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


        }

        static void TCPTest()
        {
            TcpClient TCPClient;
            //Console.WriteLine("in tcp test");
        }
    }
}
```

And the c++ code is here: http://codepad.org/f9D5bg8u (it is a stripped down version of the mono embedding sample).

When I build the C# code like this, 
    mono_runtime_invoke (method, obj, NULL, NULL); 
in the c++ side exits with code 1. 
When I comment that out and try the console.writeline, that works.

I appreciate any suggestions,
Thanks...